# Significance test of groups based on means and ranking

Tags: r, statistics

In pre-clinical pharma, many treatment groups are compared against one or more control groups for statistical significance.

Statistical tests such as Dunnett, Duncan, Schefee, Tukey, Benferonni, Dunn-Sidak Newman-Keuls, t-test etc. compare group means if data come from normal distribution, or tests such as Kruskal-Wallis, Mann-Whitney rank data if data is not normal.

I am having difficulty locating functions that perform many of these tests in R packages. Ideally they would give standard output such as test statistics, p-values showing whether compared groups are significantly different from each other.

I know that R has a package called `multcomp`, but it doesn't seem to include many of the parametric tests mentioned above. Can anyone give tell me how to find functions in R that perform these kinds of statistical tests?

Comment: Seems a bit "shopping and recommendation" unless you can change the question in some way to make it less so.

Comment: @Kev Tried to refocus the question towards "how do I find functions like this" rather than "what are the functions" in the hopes of reopening.

Comment: I recommend moving this to stats.SE, for two reasons.  1: One should know the test they seek (or at least have a good idea), which is a statistical & not a programming issue (so the audience is more appropriate on stats.SE, and users are more likely to ask about test statistics on that site).  2: On SO, this may be more likely to attract naive searching suggestions (e.g. use `sos`), which will be more likely to add to the prolific abuse of bad test statistics.

Comment: @Iterator I have no strong preferences for where this should live; I simply aimed for the edit closest to the OP's original intent that would justify reopening. In this case, I thought the `grep(ls())` answer was useful enough (as a technique, not just the list of tests themselves) that the question should be preserved.

Answer (score 7):

Amplifying Ben's answer, the `stats` package provides many classical significance tests:

```
grep(ls("package:stats"), pattern="test", value=T)
#  [1] "ansari.test"          "bartlett.test"        "binom.test"          
#  [4] "Box.test"             "chisq.test"           "cor.test"            
#  [7] "fisher.test"          "fligner.test"         "friedman.test"       
# [10] "kruskal.test"         "ks.test"              "mantelhaen.test"     
# [13] "mauchley.test"        "mauchly.test"         "mcnemar.test"        
# [16] "mood.test"            "oneway.test"          "pairwise.prop.test"  
# [19] "pairwise.t.test"      "pairwise.wilcox.test" "poisson.test"        
# [22] "power.anova.test"     "power.prop.test"      "power.t.test"        
# [25] "PP.test"              "prop.test"            "prop.trend.test"     
# [28] "quade.test"           "shapiro.test"         "t.test"              
# [31] "var.test"             "wilcox.test"
```

Additionally, `multcomp` supports many of the methods for adjusting significance under multiple comparison, including several that you mention.  To see which ones, type:

```
library(multcomp)
?contrMat

args(contrMat)  # (Just to show them here)
# function (n, type = c("Dunnett", "Tukey", "Sequen", "AVE", "Changepoint", 
#     "Williams", "Marcus", "McDermott", "UmbrellaWilliams", "GrandMean"), 
#     base = 1)
```

You may also be interested in the "Clinical Trial Design, Monitoring, and Analysis" Task View on the CRAN site.  To find it, go [here](http://cran.r-project.org/), and click on "Task Views" in the left sidebar.

**Edit:** One last note --- if you want the Mann-Whitney test, its semi-hidden.  Look for it in `?wilcox.test`.

Comment: +1 Nice way to pull the lists of supported tests & comparison types out.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the packages [stats](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/00Index.html)? For example, it has the [t-test](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/t.test.html) you're wanting, as well as various Tukey methods. Additionally, there's a [DTK](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DTK/index.html) package, which allows you to "conduct the Dunnett modified Tukey-Kramer test". The [Scheffe test](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=agricolae%3ascheffe.test) can be found in the agricolae package, the [Duncan test](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=laercio%3aLDuncan) can be found in the laercio package, and the [Bonferonni test](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=alr3%3aoutlier.t.test) can be found in the alr3 package.

You might not want to use [Newman-Keuls](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/04/09/4292.html).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing together terms for basic tests (t-test, Kruskal-Wallis, Mann-Whitney) and terms for methods to adjust for multiple comparisons(Dunnett, Duncan, Scheffe, Tukey, Bonferonni, Dunn-Sidak Newman-Keuls). In the base R you will find the `p.adjust` function that offers several methods of adjustment. You mentioned the `multcomp` package, but not the `mutoss` package. Duncan's and Scheffe's adjustment methods are in package `agricolae`. There are multiple comparisons procedures for the rank and permutation based tests implemented in the `coin` package. All of this information is readily available with the searching tools built into R and provided in the `sos` package. For the safety of our our collective pharmaceutical development,I hope you are reporting to someone with a greater knowledge than you have displayed above.